# How to use fql query to find a Youtube share

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I remember that I shared a youtube video on my Facebook page several months ago.

I want to find that youtube video.

What's the fql query that can help me find it?

Answer (score 1):

That's easy !

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,like_count,comment_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`<your-video-id>`
```